# Why did Kittridge send agents to capture/kill Ethan?

Tags: mission-impossible-dead-reckoning-1

In *Mission Impossible: Dead Reckoning Part 1*, Kittridge sends multiple US agents to capture/kill Ethan.

That's confusing as it appears (in the end) he actually wants Ethan to succeed. What's going on? Does he simply change his mind and if so, who doesn't he recall the agents at any point?

Comment: Between the beginning and the end of a film a lot usually happens. People change their minds, see things differently. Could any of that account for the change of heart? I think what this question lacks is more information: e.g. 'at the beginning of the film the protagonist is alive, at the end they are dead—what's going on?' is not really a good question for this website (and others, I hope).

Comment: @Joachim At no point in the movie does he recall these agents so I am not even sure I am right that he wants Ethan to succeed.